# hide first content of class with css

Tags: css

how can I hide FIRST CONTENT text with css but keeping SECOND CONTENT text?

Example:

```html
<div class="class_1">
    FIRST TEXT               
    <div class="class_2">
        SECOND CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The only way you can do that is if you wrap your first text with ether a span or a div and put class on it and put display: none.

Comment: @JkAlombro Then. Only with css is impossible? I know the text, and always will be the same string

Comment: Your first text and second text are both content of your class1. So if you display none that class, everything will be hidden. You cant target your first text directly because it doesnt have its own wrapper. Wrap it with span at least so that you can target it.

Answer (score 0):

#### How to can hide only text without child elements?

If it is truly impossible to separate the "**FIRST TEXT**" text into a distinct element, then the text itself should be hidden rather than the element.

In this case, you can play with settings such as `font-size`, `color`, `line-height`, and `visibility` all of which **can assist in displaying the text**. Of course, the **child element's settings must still override those of the parent element**.

#### Example

```css
.class_1 {
  color: transparent;
  line-height: 0;
}

.class_2 {
  color: black;
  line-height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="class_1">
  FIRST TEXT               
  <div class="class_2">
    SECOND CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
```

In my example, I **removed the font color from class_1**, which meant that I had to reset the font color for class_2 to black. This left an empty space where "FIRST CONTENT" used to be. To **remove the empty space, I had to set the line-height to 0**, but then I needed to set the line-height to "auto" (or another appropriate value) in the child element. If it's important that the element cannot be selected in any way, then you should set the visibility property to "hidden" in the parent element and "visible" in every child element.

Comment: this is a very hacky and dirty solution but well, it gets the job done lol.

Comment: The best solution, of course, would be to have each text placed in its own separate element. I would try to avoid the format provided in your example if possible. However, in my response, I adhered to the request to only solve the issue with CSS. After all, it may be the case that you don't have the ability to modify the HTML. In such cases, we must find a way to be resourceful.

Answer (score 0):

CSS does not support targetting text nodes, only element nodes, so you cannot directly target `FIRST TEXT`. You can hide `class_1` and show `class_2`:

```css
.class_1 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.class_2 {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="class_1">
        FIRST TEXT               
        <div class="class_2">
              SECOND CONTENT
        </div>
</div>
```

Note that this has an effect on layout, since `visibility` just hides the content, but does not remove it. You cannot use `display: none` on `.class_1`, because it and its entire subtree is then gone, and `display: block` on `.class_2` will not be considered.

To be able to target `.class_2` by itself, wrap it into an element:

```css
.class_1 > *:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="class_1">
        <span>FIRST TEXT</span>
        <div class="class_2">
              SECOND CONTENT
        </div>
</div>
```

`span` would also work in this simple example instead of `.class_1 > *:first-child`; it is hard to say what would be the best in a non-simplified example.

Comment: @tacoshy: Not true. See [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#visibility): "See dynamic row and column effects in tables [CSS2] and collapsed flex items in flex layout [CSS-FLEXBOX-1]. In all other cases, however, (i.e. unless otherwise specified) this simply makes the box invisible, just like hidden."

Comment: My bad, i stand corrected

Answer (score 0):

Use the `visibility` property. Then you can collapse the text node while keeping the element node visible:

```css
.class_1 {
  visibility: collapse;
}

.class_2 {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="class_1">
  FIRST TEXT
  <div class="class_2">
    SECOND CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Outside `flex` or `table`, `collapse` is the same as `hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is with setting the `font-size`s, like so:

```css
.class_1 {
  font-size: 0;
}

.class_2 {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="class_1">
  FIRST TEXT
  <div class="class_2">
    SECOND CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
```